# Are some new html5 as nav and footer indispensable?

Tags: html, footer, nav

Are new html tags as nav, footer, menu, article and so on indispensable or I can omit it?
Is a code without these tag considered as obsolete, as, for example, a code with an old doctype (

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 ?>
```

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're more like new options that give you more control over the central page element, and so, make it easy to create web pages, nothing more.

You can absolutely use HTML5 without using all those new tags. Just create a simple .html file, then add whatever you want. The choice of the tags depends on what **you** want to do.
You can read this : http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype